# Use print_pdf in the background on node save?

Tags: 7, nodes, files

As the Print module's creation of a PDF can be quite slow (and use a lot of memory/CPU), is it possible to save a PDF into the `public://` files area each time a node is saved?

Has anyone done this? Presumably you could call a save-PDF function on `hook_node_presave` but I'm not sure what the next step is. Call a print-PDF function with a file path? Where is that print-PDF function and how would you call it?

Answer (score 0):

The function used from that module to output PDF is [`print_pdf_generate_html()`](http://api.drupalhelp.net/api/print/print_pdf--print_pdf.pages.inc/function/print_pdf_generate_html/7), which gets a filename as last parameter.

To understand what to pass as first argument, see [`print_pdf_generate_path()`](http://api.drupalhelp.net/api/print/print_pdf--print_pdf.pages.inc/function/print_pdf_generate_path/7), which is the function calling `print_pdf_generate_html()`. In particular, see the following code.

```
$print = print_controller($path, $cid, PRINT_PDF_FORMAT);
if ($print === FALSE) {
  return;
}
```